# Can I use hadoop in Jupyter/IPython

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, ipython, jupyter

Can I use Hadoop & MapReduce in Jupyter/IPython? Is there something similar to what PySpark for Spark is?

Comment: We do have python api for hadoop http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/  . Can your question be more specific on what you try to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. Many Frameworks like [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Hadoop+Streaming), [mrjob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob) and [dumbo](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki) to name a few. The techical aspect of including these in Jupyter should concist of either `subprocess.Popen()` calls or typical python imports, depending on the framework.

A nice overview/critique of some of these Frameworks can be found in this cloudera [blogpost](http://web.archive.org/web/20190318040135/https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/).